# How to combine 2 files using python using custom format

Tags: python, file, concatenation

```
with open('file_1.txt', 'r') as file :
    filedata_s = file.read()
with open('file_2.txt', 'r') as file :
    filedata_d = file.read()
print (filedata_s+filedata_d)
```

file 1 contains name\age\occupation... etc file 2 contains Bob\16\student...
Desired output is

```
Name :- ‘Bob’
Age  :- '16'
Occ  :-'student'
```

Comment: It is possible to do it. Can you post the code that you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: Input files look like

```
name/age/occupation
```

```
Bob/16/student
```

If you don't care about padding in the output, you could try:

```
with open('file_1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('file_2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    for line1, line2 in zip(
        file1.read().rstrip().split("/"), file2.read().rstrip().split("/")
    ):
        print(f"{line1} :- '{line2}'")
```

The output would look like:

```
name :- 'Bob'
age :- '16'
occupation :- 'student'
```

If you want to write it into a new file:

```
with open('file_1.txt', 'r') as fin1, open('file_2.txt', 'r') as fin2,\
     open('file_3.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(
        f"{line1} :- '{line2}'\n"
        for line1, line2 in zip(
            fin1.read().rstrip().split("/"), fin2.read().rstrip().split("/")
        )
    )
```

If you care about the padding, you could try:

```
lines = []
for filename in ('file_1.txt', 'file_2.txt'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        lines.append(file.read().rstrip().split("/"))
padding = max(map(len, lines[0]))
for line1, line2 in zip(*lines):
    print(f"{line1.ljust(padding)} :- '{line2}'")
```

The output would look like:

```
name       :- 'Bob'
age        :- '16'
occupation :- 'student'
```

Here you have to evaluate the first file fist and use `padding = max(map(len, lines[0]))` to determine the maximal string length, and then use it with [`str.ljust()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to adjust the output accordingly.

Writing into a new file:

```
...
with open('file_3.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(
        f"{line1.ljust(padding)} :- '{line2}'\n" for line1, line2 in zip(*lines)
    )
```

---

If you have multiple input lines, I'd use the `csv` module from the standard library, like

```
import csv

with open("file_1.txt", "r") as fin1, open("file_2.txt", "r") as fin2:
    reader1 = csv.reader(fin1, delimiter="/")
    reader2 = csv.reader(fin2, delimiter="/")
    for row1, row2 in zip(reader1, reader2):
        for item1, item2 in zip(row1, row2):
            print(f"{item1} :- '{item2}'")
```

or with padding

```
with open("file_1.txt", "r") as file:
    padding = max(
        len(item) for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter="/") for item in row
    )

with open("file_1.txt", "r") as fin1, open("file_2.txt", "r") as fin2:
    reader1 = csv.reader(fin1, delimiter="/")
    reader2 = csv.reader(fin2, delimiter="/")
    for row1, row2 in zip(reader1, reader2):
        for item1, item2 in zip(row1, row2):
            print(f"{item1.ljust(padding)} :- '{item2}'")
```

Comment: @sampath So there's no linebreak (`"\n"`) in the files, just one long line with items separated by `"/"`?

Comment: Hi @Timus thank you very much for the answer but i'm still having 2 minor problem that i need to mention that the data in my files are in the format of file1 data is like yes there is no line break("/n") in the file  **name/age/occupation....etc**  and  file2 data is like **bob/16/student.....etc** (**when i'm running for loop the output is in the form of **n :- b a :-o m :- b........soon **)  and another problem is that **'name' :- 'bob'** the output need to be in single quotes please consider this file inputs suggest on this and once again thanks for helping me

Comment: @sampath See edit: Is that more like it?

Comment: Wow..well done...my Friend Thank you very much working as expected you saved me

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('file_3.txt', 'w') as file_3:
    with open('file_1.txt', 'r') as file_1:
        with open('file_2.txt', 'r') as file_2:
            for line1, line2 in zip(file_1, file_2):
                print(line1.strip(), line2.strip(), file=file_3)
```

Comment: Note that you can open more than one file per `with` statement: `with open('a', 'w') as out, open('b', 'r') as in1, open('c', 'r') as in2:` in this way you avoid having multiple indention levels

Comment: Please provide explanation, code only answers do not help others in gaining an understanding why this particular solution works/is advisable.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def read_list(filename):
    result = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            result.append(line.strip())
    return result


list_s = read_list('file_1.txt')
list_d = read_list('file_2.txt')

for item in zip(list_s, list_d):
    print(item)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).